# use PAT and static nat at the same time as inside and global nat interface

Tags: cisco, nat, snat, dnat

I've setup a network consisting a "AUTOMAÇÃO->Automation" lan, "Rede interna->Internal network" and the WAN (f0/1). Every device is cisco except 200A (fortigate).

Everyone on internal network must access internet using PAT but automation should not. On the 200A router side, there is a GRE tunnel to 1905-sec router and clients from which network can access each other.
So, I need to map an internal IP from "Internal networw" on 1905-sec router to translate that into a internal IP on automation network.

- Internal network 1905-sec: 192.168.21.0/24
- Automation network 1905-sec: 192.168.250.0/24
- Internal network 200A: 192.168.14.0/24

f0/1 is outside nat, f0/0 is inside nat. Since I have to map a IP of internal network 192.168.21.1 to be translated into 192.168.250.1 and routed to f1/0 I can't make f0/0 be outside and inside at the same time.

How can I use PAT for normal operating mode and static nat to translate 192.168.21.1 as a global address and 192.168.250.1 as a inside address witout messing with PAT?

**EDIT: I did it! I used NVI.**
checkout the solution: http://www.ciscozine.com/nat-virtual-interface-aka-nvi-what-is-that/

[image]

Comment: PAT is actually incorrect terminology. According to the RFCs, e.g. [RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations, Section 4.1.2, Network Address Port Translation (NAPT)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2663#section-4.1.2), "_NAPT allows a set of hosts to share a single external address._"

Comment: You should create an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: I can accept in 17 hours.

Comment: PAT is really made up. The RFCs use NAPT for what some people call PAT. See _[RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations, Section 4.1.2 Network Address Port Translation (NAPT)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2663#section-4.1.2)_: "_NAPT extends the notion of translation one step further by also translating transport identifier (e.g., TCP and UDP port numbers, ICMP query identifiers). This allows the transport identifiers of a number of private hosts to be multiplexed into the transport identifiers of a single external address._" There is more in the RFC.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved using NAT virtual interface.
http://www.ciscozine.com/nat-virtual-interface-aka-nvi-what-is-that/

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep poppiing up forever, looking for an answer.